# Detect when some Numpad key is pressed, Form not on focus

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble trying to find a way to do this.

I want my application to display a message box for the user whenever he presses some key on the numpad. The main problem is that it must be done with the form out of focus. Can't find any way to do this using VB.NET

Answer (score 2):

Declare :

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Integer
Dim result As Integer
```

formload:

```
Timer1.interval = 1
timer1.start()
```

Timer1.tick :

```
For i = 1 To 255 
result = 0 
result = GetAsyncKeyState (i)
If result = -32767 Then 
            If i = 103 Then
                MsgBox("Num 7")
            End If
End If 
Next i
```

:)

Comment: Thanks, man. It works just Like I needed. But I have another question, where can I get the value from all keys on the keyboard?
Like you used on: **If i = 103 Then**

Just got it, if someone get here by Google: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html

Comment: Another question, How can I convert the key value to key code? So I don't have to test each key?

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually talking about is called a Global KeyboardHook since you want to listen for Messages not directed at your Program. There is a nice library on CodePlex([Application and Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks Library](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/releases/view/73244)) that implements this for .Net.

Here is a very simple example, You will need to download above library and add the `MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor` to your References.

```
Imports MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor
Imports MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.WinApi

Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents myKeyboardHookManager As KeyboardHookListener
    Dim hookEnabled As Boolean
    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        myKeyboardHookManager = New KeyboardHookListener(New GlobalHooker())
        myKeyboardHookManager.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub HookManager_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.NumPad0 To Keys.NumPad9
                MessageBox.Show("KeyCode = " & e.KeyCode & vbCrLf & "Number = " & (e.KeyCode - 96))

        End Select


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If hookEnabled Then
            hookEnabled = False
            RemoveHandler myKeyboardHookManager.KeyDown, AddressOf HookManager_KeyDown
        Else
            hookEnabled = True
            AddHandler myKeyboardHookManager.KeyDown, AddressOf HookManager_KeyDown
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I get this error:

An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor, Version=3.0.1.9571, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: @blacblu What version of visual studio are you running. You may need to verify that you are including the proper dll 32bit or 64bit. Also make sure you have downloaded the project and compiled it.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2012, tried with both, 64 and 32, though with 32 I can't import MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.WinApi 
EDIT: Manage to include the .winApi with 32 and it worked, Thank You

Comment: @blacblu Glad it worked for you, I tested it using vs2012 and had to change it from AnyCpu to x64